# How to register parameters in URL in Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make an URL which accepts a query after "?" operator , which will looks like this "/search?q=" . The question how should I make this particular URL in express JS and also how I can integrate an "&" operator in it .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to register a route `/search` and all query parameters will be in `req.query`. It supports `&` for several parameters as well as a parameter with several values like this `?q=1&q=2&q=3`.

Comment: This is if we want to get the requested query by user but I want to register parameter in url "/search?q=" . So in express , how should I write , app.get("/search?q=" , (req,res)) -->something like that or it will be wrong ??

Comment: You don't need to register query parameters because they are dynamic. Just register `/search` and look at `req.query`